# Find Limits of this function

Tags: calculus, limits

Find the limits for this function

$$\lim_{x\to {\pi \over 4}}\frac{\sqrt[3]{\tan(x)} -1}{2\sin^2x - 1} $$

Comment: Two whoever's editing the $45^\circ$ to $\pi/4$, note that it was $45$ in the original version.

Comment: I suspect that for the numerator OP intended $\sqrt[3]{\tan x}-1$.

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger usually you don't write degrees but radians... and 45 is confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we have a ${0 \over 0}$ form, you can apply L'Hospital's rule:

$$\lim_{x\to {\pi \over 4}}\frac{\sqrt[3]{\tan(x)} -1}{2\sin^2x - 1} =  \lim_{x\to {\pi \over 4}}\left(\frac{1}{\cos^2 x \tan^{\frac{2}{3}} x} \cdot \frac{1}{4 \cos x \sin x}\right) = {2\over 3} \cdot {1 \over 2} = {1\over 3}$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: The bottom is $\sin^2 x-\cos^2 x$, while the top is $\frac{\tan x-1}{\tan^{2/3} x+\tan^{1/3} x+1}$. Note that $\tan x-1=\frac{\sin x-\cos x}{\cos x}$.

---

---

---